# Is there GPS data to test a trilateration program against?

Tags: gps, gis, trilateration

I'm writing a C program to perform GPS trilateration. I'd like some sample data and outputs to test my program against. Where can I find this data?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at NMEA data since this is a common standard. You can generate your own information to test with and then you will actually know what to expect as data. Some example strings can be found at:

http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#stream

I think the GPGSV data is raw(ish) satellite information. Of course most GPS data has already been triangulated for you. Also, you should note that the raw "round trip" data is inherently noisey due to waves in the layers of the upper atmosphere.

Comment: What I'm really looking for here sample (digital) data received from the GPS  satellites.